# Livepatch in 22.04 LTS not working

Tags: canonical-livepatch

Ever since i upgraded to 22.04 in March I was not able to attach my Machine to Livepatch. Back then I (probably rightfully so) assumed it was because 22.04 was still in beta.

But after official release to this day i am not able to activate Livepatch. Whenever I try via the GUI i get the error "Failed to attach. Please try again."

In the Terminal it errors as follows:

```
Failed to connect to authentication server
Check your Internet connection and try again.
Failed to attach machine. See https://ubuntu.com/advantage
```

Anybody having the same issue and / or possibly a fix?

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue on a fresh install. After registration I found the GUI activation does not work.

In your error report there is a link listed, https//----------
go there and register as the personal user free choice which will give you a maximum of three machines to register. Follow the instructions on the registration.
Once registered go to your TERMINAL and enter: `sudo ua enable livepatch`

(It will check your registration and enable livepatch if you are registered correctly.)

Comment: Thank you. sudo ua enable livepatch did it.
Launching the gui, livepatch shows up as enabled.

Comment: Worked for me as well. Thanks!